# File Roller Can't Uncompress an Encrypted 7z File?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, compression, 7-zip

File Roller (Or Archive Manager) seems to be broken somehow when it comes to 7z files. I have an encrypted archive for which I know the password, but file roller doesn't even give me the option to enter it before deciding that it can't handle it and displays an error. Is there any way I can fix this issue? I'm using a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 with all the latest updates from `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Either install 7-Zip for Linux (http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) or, If you dual-boot, just run Windows 7-Ziip (under Wine).

Comment: Do you have one of the 7z packages installed (7z or 7zr? don't remember the name right now) and can you view/uncompress in the terminal ok?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04. Using `7zr (A) 9.02` on the command line gave the error you show on several .7z archives.

Run this to fix it.

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're at -1. I'm using a completely different distro (Solus) but with the same problem. Installing p7zip did seamlessly make File Roller start accepting passworded 7-zip files. I repeat; the tip above does _not_ install merely a different tool. File Roller apparently uses it behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this running Ubuntu 18.04. Turns out you need to install a dependency or use different tooling to extract/compress encrypted .7z files.

Option 1: Install p7zip-full to add support for 7z in Archive Manager

- `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`
- This option adds 7z support existing applications [such as Ark, File Roller or Nautilus](https://packages.debian.org/sid/p7zip-full)
- The support in Archive Manager seems to be quite good! For the 7z format, it can encrypt files, encrypt file list, and split into multiple files. You have to carefully use 'Open With Other Application' though or you'll end up fighting with Nautilus.
- Nautilus (aka Files) allows you to use .7z, but doesn't seem to work with encrypted .7z files. When opening an encrypted .7z, the 'Files' app does not ask for a password and instead gets stuck trying to open the archive. Also, nautilus doesn't appear to show any encryption related options when creating new .7z archives.

Option 2: Try other tools

- There is a tool in the software center called 'P7Zip - Desktop'. The notes indicate that it is a 'soft-fork of p7zip and it it does seem to work pretty well.
- There are also various command line options you might investigate as well.